# Arduino library error: use of deleted function

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing a library for Arduino. This library has to use the existing TFT_eSPI library. When I try to compile the following I get

> /.../sketch/src/Display/Display.cpp: In static member function 'static void Display::begin()':
> /.../sketch/src/Display/Display.cpp:16:9: error: use of deleted function 'TFT_eSPI& TFT_eSPI::operator=(TFT_eSPI&&)'
> tft = TFT_eSPI();
> ^
> In file included from /.../sketch/src/Display/Display.h:12:0,
> from /.../sketch/src/Display/Display.cpp:9:
> /Users/luigisc/Documents/Arduino/libraries/TFT_eSPI/TFT_eSPI.h:359:7: note: 'TFT_eSPI& TFT_eSPI::operator=(TFT_eSPI&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
> class TFT_eSPI : public Print {
> ^
> /Users/luigisc/Documents/Arduino/libraries/TFT_eSPI/TFT_eSPI.h:359:7: error: non-static reference member 'fs::FS& TFT_eSPI::fontFS', can't use default assignment operator

**Display.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Display.h"

/*Global objects' declaration and initialization*/

void Display::begin(){
    //Display initializing
    tft = TFT_eSPI();

    tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.setRotation(1);

}

// PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

void Display::drawGIF(GIFDRAW *pDraw){
    uint8_t *s;
    uint16_t *d, *usPalette, usTemp[320];
    int x, y, iWidth;

    iWidth = pDraw->iWidth;
    if (iWidth > tft.width())
        iWidth = tft.width();
    usPalette = pDraw->pPalette;
    y = pDraw->iY + pDraw->y; // current line

    s = pDraw->pPixels;
    if (pDraw->ucDisposalMethod == 2) // restore to background color
    {
        for (x=0; x<iWidth; x++)
        {
            if (s[x] == pDraw->ucTransparent)
                s[x] = pDraw->ucBackground;
        }
        pDraw->ucHasTransparency = 0;
    }
    // Apply the new pixels to the main image
    if (pDraw->ucHasTransparency) // if transparency used
    {
        uint8_t *pEnd, c, ucTransparent = pDraw->ucTransparent;
        int x, iCount;
        pEnd = s + iWidth;
        x = 0;
        iCount = 0; // count non-transparent pixels
        while(x < iWidth)
        {
            c = ucTransparent-1;
            d = usTemp;
            while (c != ucTransparent && s < pEnd)
            {
                c = *s++;
                if (c == ucTransparent) // done, stop
                {
                    s--; // back up to treat it like transparent
                }
                else // opaque
                {
                    *d++ = usPalette[c];
                    iCount++;
                }
            } // while looking for opaque pixels
            if (iCount) // any opaque pixels?
            {
                tft.setAddrWindow(pDraw->iX+x, y, iCount, 1);
                tft.startWrite();
                tft.pushPixels(usTemp, iCount);
                tft.endWrite();
                x += iCount;
                iCount = 0;
            }
            // no, look for a run of transparent pixels
            c = ucTransparent;
            while (c == ucTransparent && s < pEnd)
            {
                c = *s++;
                if (c == ucTransparent)
                    iCount++;
                else
                    s--;
            }
            if (iCount)
            {
                x += iCount; // skip these
                iCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        s = pDraw->pPixels;
        // Translate the 8-bit pixels through the RGB565 palette (already byte reversed)
        for (x=0; x<iWidth; x++)
            usTemp[x] = usPalette[*s++];
        tft.setAddrWindow(pDraw->iX, y, iWidth, 1);
        tft.startWrite();
        tft.pushPixels(usTemp, iWidth);
        tft.endWrite();
    }
}

// PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

void Display::displayGIF(const uint8_t *gif_file, int gif_size, int nTimes){

    if (gif.open((uint8_t *)gif_file, gif_size, drawGIF)){

        for(int i=0;i<nTimes;i++){
            gif.playFrame(true, NULL);
            while(gif.playFrame(true, NULL)){}
        }

        gif.close();

    }else{
        tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
        tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
        tft.setTextSize(2);
        tft.drawString("ERR: Can't load GIF", 0, tft.width()/2);
    }

}
```

**Display.h**

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>
#include <AnimatedGIF.h>

class Display {

  public:
    static void begin();
    static void displayGIF(const uint8_t *gif_file, int gif_size, int nTimes);

  private:
    static void drawGIF(GIFDRAW *pDraw);
    static AnimatedGIF gif;
    static TFT_eSPI tft;

};

#endif
```

**Edit**

I reported all the code, also the function drawGif that need to be static.

Comment: Apparently the class is neither copyable nor moveable. But why are you are writing `tft = TFT_eSPI();` in the first place? That seems unnecessary

Comment: TFT_eSPI is non copyable. I.e. copy constructor and assignment operator declared with `= delete` specifier. This is a protection mechanism. What you can do, TFT_eSPI must not be static, it have no sence. Make you Display facade class non copyable, and initalize TFT_eSPI in constructor, i.e. like this `class Display { Display(const Display&) = delete; Display& operator=(const Display& ) = delete; Display() : tft() {     tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.setRotation(1); } } ....  Display dsp;`

Comment: @VictorGubin I need tft to be static because I need a function which uses tft that must be static: it will be used as a callback (and this must be static) in another function call.

`gif.open(..., drawGIF)` where drawGIF has to use tft and be static

Comment: We need more context to help you with this. It seems like we are on XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `TFT_eSPI` instance doesn't belong in your `Display` class at all. You seem to use `Display` similar to a `namespace` since it only has `static` members (both variables and functions).

If you only want one single `TFT_eSPI` instance everywhere, you could create a free function returning a `TFT_eSPI&` to that one instance. Example:

`Display.h`

```cpp
class Display {
    // static TFT_eSPI tft; // remove this
};

TFT_eSPI& tft();            // add a declaration of a free function
```

`Display.cpp`

```cpp
void Display::begin(){
    //Display initializing
    //tft = TFT_eSPI();     // remove this
}

TFT_eSPI& tft() {           // add definition of the free function
    static TFT_eSPI instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Then in all places where you now do `tft.something()` you instead do `tft().something()`. The `AnimatedGIF` instance could be handled the same way.

`Display` could also be made into `namespace Display` and all the current member functions could be made into free functions in that namespace since `Display` does not keep any internal state.